# Java: paintComponent() Oval is not appearing in Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

I'm trying to learn how to draw an oval in java but the paintComponent I made is not being called by anything, and attempting to call it only causes more issues.

The program runs successfully but the image I want displayed isn't showing up.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class TEST2{
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    g.drawOval(70, 70, 100, 100);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TEST2 gui = new TEST2();
    gui.setUpFrame();
}   
public void setUpFrame(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Images should be in this program");
    frame.setSize(600,300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}    

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paintComponent() method is a method that you **override** and it should be accessed inside a class that extends JPanel.  You can create a new class that extends JPanel and override the paintComponent() method to draw your oval.  You will also have to add the new JPanel to your JFrame for it to display.  I modified your code below it should display the oval now.  As Madprogrammer noted you should probably construct your GUI within the context of the edt to avoid concurrency issues but I will omit that for simplicity.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test gui = new Test();
        gui.setUpFrame();
    }

    public void setUpFrame() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Images should be in this program");
        frame.setSize(600, 300);
        JPanel oval = new oval();
        frame.setContentPane(oval);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    public class oval extends JPanel{
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawOval(70, 70, 100, 100);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: 1- Call `super.paintComponent` before it starts drawing all sorts of weird and wonderful artifacts all over you component; 2- Consider using the `@Override` annotation when overriding methods; 3- `paintComponent` should never be `public`; 4- You really should create your UI's from within the context of the EDT

Answer (score 1):

Start by taking a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

In order to be able to perform custom painting in Swing, you must...

1. Inherit from a swing based component (like `JComponent` or `JPanel`)
2. You must then override it's `paintComponent` method and perform you custom painting within this method.
3. Add this component to something that is displayable (like a `JFrame`)

You should make sure to call `super.paintComponent` before doing any custom painting

To ensure that you're not making any (common) mistakes, you should use the `@Override` annotation

As an example...

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test2 extends JPanel {

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawOval(70, 70, 100, 100);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setTitle("Images should be in this program");
                frame.add(new Test2());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            }
        });
    }

}
```